# What's the differences between tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES and tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys

> GLOBAL_VARIABLES: the default collection of Variable objects, shared
>   across distributed environment (model variables are subset of these).
>   See tf.compat.v1.global_variables for more details. Commonly, all
>   TRAINABLE_VARIABLES variables will be in MODEL_VARIABLES, and all
>   MODEL_VARIABLES variables will be in GLOBAL_VARIABLES
>
> TRAINABLE_VARIABLES: the subset of Variable objects that will be
>   trained by an optimizer. See tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables for more
>   details.

So as I understand `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` is subset of `GLOBAL_VARIABLES`, so what else `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` contain?

Also for this simple example statement `Commonly, all TRAINABLE_VARIABLES variables will be in MODEL_VARIABLES, and all MODEL_VARIABLES variables will be in GLOBAL_VARIABLES` don't hold:

```
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 5
IMAGE_WIDTH = 5
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.variable_scope('my_scope', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        x_ph = tf.placeholder(
                dtype=tf.float32,
                shape=[None, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3],
                name='input'
            )

        x_tf = tf.layers.conv2d(x_ph, 32, 1, 1, padding='valid')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        x_np = np.random.rand(1, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)

        out_np = sess.run(x_tf, {x_ph:x_np})

        print('out_np.shape', out_np.shape)

        print('-'*60)
        global_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
        print('len(global_vars)', len(global_vars))
        print('global_vars params:', sum([np.prod(var.shape) for var in global_vars]))
        print(global_vars)

        print('-'*60)
        model_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES)
        print('len(model_vars)', len(model_vars))
        print('model_vars params:', sum([np.prod(var.shape) for var in model_vars]))
        print(model_vars)

        print('-'*60)
        trainable_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
        print('len(trainable_vars)', len(trainable_vars))
        print('trainable_vars params:', sum([np.prod(var.shape) for var in trainable_vars]))
        print(trainable_vars)
```

Output:

```
out_np.shape (1, 5, 5, 32)
------------------------------------------------------------
len(global_vars) 2
global_vars params: 128
[<tf.Variable 'my_scope/conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1, 3, 32) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'my_scope/conv2d/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref>]
------------------------------------------------------------
len(model_vars) 0
model_vars params: 0
[]
------------------------------------------------------------
len(trainable_vars) 2
trainable_vars params: 128
[<tf.Variable 'my_scope/conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1, 3, 32) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'my_scope/conv2d/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

So questions are:

1. Why `Commonly, all TRAINABLE_VARIABLES variables will be in MODEL_VARIABLES, and all MODEL_VARIABLES variables will be in GLOBAL_VARIABLES` don't hold for this example.
2. What additional variables `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` contain besides `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`? Is it true that `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` will be always subset of `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` or they can just intersect partially?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** All of this applies to TF version **1** only, as all variable collections have been deprecated and (IIRC) won't be in TF v2.

#### Starting from question 2:

> What additional variables GLOBAL_VARIABLES contain besides TRAINABLE_VARIABLES?

`global_step`, for example, is a global variable which is not trainable.
It's a variable, because you update it at every step, it's not trainable because it's not part of the optimization process (as in, it's not a weight/bias that is altered in order to minimize the loss).

> Is it true that TRAINABLE_VARIABLES will be always subset of GLOBAL_VARIABLES or they can just intersect partially?

In principle, the two groups can just intersect partially, although this would be very odd. An example I can think of would be something like a custom distributed training environment where each machine has its own optimizer and where some of the trainable variables are defined as local variables (i.e., each machine has its own copy and these copies are not kept in sync). Why would you do that? No clue. But in principle, it's possible.

#### Then about question 1:

I believe the statement you quote is missing an important clarification: **you** need to put the variables in the `MODEL_VARIABLES` collection, by default variables are only added to the `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` collection and, if `trainable=True` also to `TRAINABLE_VARIABLS`. TF can't know on its own which variables are necessary for inference and which are only for training (e.g., networks with auxiliary heads used for training only), so it's left to the network architect. As a side note, I've never seen that collection used anywhere and I believe it's currently unused.